# pycharm error:cannot perform refactoring using selected element(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am running python 3.5.0 on pycharm community edition 4.5.4, and every time i try to insert an open square bracket to , for example, define a list it just gives me an error saying: "**Cannot perform refactoring using selected element(s)**"

This is really confusing because it seemed to work fine on the older python versions (3.4.3).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using [Right Alt] + F to insert square bracket (for example with Czech keyboard layout), pycharm interprets it as [Ctrl] + [Alt] + F, which is a shortcut to some sort of refactoring.

You can change the shortcut to something else in File - Settings - Keymap - Main menu - Refactor - Extract - Field..